# Восстановление данных Mac Os после переустановки

Tags: mac, apple, восстановление, recovery, sierra

Предистория: запустил обновление OS, после того, как написало, что надо перегрузится - перегрузился, выскочил экран с установкой обновлений, написало около 30 мин. Когда оставалось мин 10, снова сказало, что надо перегрузится. Перегрузился и все... Вижу яблоко на черном экране и все.

Пробовал проверить жосткий диск (безопасный режим работает) - не помогло. После часов 2-3 я сдался и поставил с нуля OS Sierra (до этого была OS Sierra High Beta).

После установки все заработало. Но есть одно но - можно ли вернуть данные? Специально не скачиваю ничего, так как знаю, что если записать что то поверх - точно не восстановишь.

Пробовал 2 программы - Disk Drill и R-Studio (последняя на винде когда то давно очень помогла, нашла все) - результата 0, они не видят прежних файлов, вообще никаких((

Может ли это быть связано с тем, что у меня была новая файловая система от Apple - APSF?

И какие еще программы или методы есть, что бы вернуть данные? Буду благодарен за любую помощь